# Sprockets not adding fingerprint to files added in scss file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I'm having an issue with Rails, Sprockets, SCSS and them not adding a fingerprint to the generated image files.

When I try to precompile my assets in an environment other than development, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Custom asset_path helper is not implemented

Extend your environment context with a custom method.

    environment.context_class.class_eval do
      def asset_path(path, options = {})
      end
    end
```

So I add the following to an initializer:

```
 Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
   def asset_path(path, options = {})
   end
 end
```

Which causes the error to go away, although I don't know if this is the right way about fixing the issue. It then produces a new error:

```
undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
```

However, if I add the following code:

```
 Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
   def asset_path(path, options = {})
    "/assets/#{path}"       
   end
 end
```

It precompiles fine, but then the generated css does not have the fingerprint generated at the end of the url and therefore doesn't load when viewing the page.

The weird thing is that images that aren't added in a scss file, like in an img tag in the html, has the fingerprint appended fine and shows up when viewing the page.

Here is an example of some scss that doesn't load the fingerprint:

```
background: $blue url( asset-path('hero/hero-bg.jpg') ) repeat-x;
```

I'm running Rails 4.0.2. Here is my gemfile: https://gist.github.com/anthonycollini/8025540

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to define `asset_path` since that is a helper that is already provided by Rails. It looks like you may have missed `<%= %>` when using `asset_path` in your scss file.

`background: $blue url(<%= asset-path('hero/hero-bg.jpg') %>) repeat-x;`

Also, don't forget to add the `.erb` file extension on your scss file like `example.css.scss.erb`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Although not the issue, it helped me resolve the issue, which was removing a commented out/unneeded font-face declaration in my styles. The file this code was in did not end in .erb, which is why it was throwing the error. I removed all the initializers, etc, and it works great. Thanks for the help.